# How to control number of rows in one page?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am working with *iReport 5.2.0* and i am trying to generate the report from xml file.
The problem  i am facing is that say i have 200 records that is satisfying the Xpath query condition.

Question 1:
The output that i am getting is showing several pages and only FOUR RECORDS PER PAGE.
i want the output such that as many record can be displayed in one page and then only second page starts.

Question 2:
Can i set the limit 50 records per page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the limit per page in iReport. To achieve this follow these steps:-

```
 1:-  Add "Report Group". To add "Report Group" go to "Report Inspector" section
      and right click on the report and chose "Add Report Group".

 2:-  Give any "Group name" and select "Group by following expression" option 
      and use this expression

        $V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1 - ( ($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1) % 30 )
```

where 30 means if query returns 100 rows then it will take only 30 rows per chart.